# Replace value of dictionary with key from another dictionary

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

I have the following dictionaries in Python 2.7

```
dict1 = {'a':0, 'b':1, 'c':2,'d':3,'e':4,'f':5}
dict2 = {'a':3, 'b':4, 'c':5}
```

I would like to iterate through the values in dict2 and replace them with the keys that correspond to those values in dict1 with the final dictionary being

```
dict3 = {'a':'d','b':'e','c':'f'}
```

I am trying to learn programming and have spent more than 3 hours trying different ways and searching the internet. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you list some of those ways so we can guide you there?

Comment: What if `dict1` has several different keys mapping to the same integer? What behavior do you expect in this case?

Comment: The keys map to different integers. I apologize for not mentioning that. @ndpu method is what I was trying, but wasn't able to figure out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
>>> dict1 = {'a':0, 'b':1, 'c':2,'d':3,'e':4,'f':5}
>>> dict2 = {'a':3, 'b':4, 'c':5}

>>> d1 = {v:k for k,v in dict1.iteritems()}
>>> d1
{0: 'a', 1: 'b', 2: 'c', 3: 'd', 4: 'e', 5: 'f'}

>>> dict3 = {k:d1[v] for k,v in dict2.iteritems()}
>>> dict3
{'a': 'd', 'c': 'f', 'b': 'e'}
```

Comment: Since we're on Python 2.7, it might be a little better to use `iteritems()` instead of `items()`.

Comment: thanks- this works. now I just need to understand how it works :)

Answer (score 2):

If there are different integers in `dict1`, you can make value->key dictionary from `dict1` and then use it to find corresponding keys from `dict1` for `dict2`:

```
>>> dict1_inverse = dict((v,k) for (k,v) in dict1.iteritems())
>>> dict((k, dict1_inverse[v]) for k,v in dict2.iteritems())
{'a': 'd', 'c': 'f', 'b': 'e'}
```

But if there are several keys in `dict1` mapping for the same integer, you might get not what you want, e.g.:

```
>>> dict1 = {'a':0, 'b':1, 'c':4,'d':3,'e':4,'f':5}
>>> dict1_inverse = dict((v,k) for (k,v) in dict1.iteritems())
>>> dict((k, dict1_inverse[v]) for k,v in dict2.iteritems())
{'a': 'd', 'c': 'f', 'b': 'e'}
```

Here `b` could map to `c` or `e`, and the result may be different depending on where in the hash-table these keys are in the `dict1`.

In this case you may want something like this:

```
>>> dict1 = {'a':0, 'b':1, 'c':4,'d':3,'e':4,'f':5}
>>> dict1_inverse = {}
>>> for k,v in dict1.iteritems():
    dict1_inverse.setdefault(v, []).append(k)


>>> dict1_inverse
{0: ['a'], 1: ['b'], 3: ['d'], 4: ['c', 'e'], 5: ['f']}
>>> dict((k, dict1_inverse[v]) for k,v in dict2.iteritems())
{'a': ['d'], 'c': ['f'], 'b': ['c', 'e']}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> d1
{'a': 0, 'c': 2, 'b': 1, 'e': 4, 'd': 3, 'f': 5}
>>> d2
{'a': 3, 'c': 5, 'b': 4}
>>> d3 = {k:k2 for k2,v2 in d1.iteritems() for k,v in d2.iteritems() if v==v2}  
>>> d3
{'a': 'd', 'c': 'f', 'b': 'e'}
```

Comment: This will not scale nicely because of the nested iteration.

Answer (score 0):

```
dict3={}
for k,v in dict2.items():
    dict3[k]=sorted(dict1.keys())[v]
```